# dynamically change (ASC/DESC) sorting data depending on conditional state in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

When i declare a cursor it does sorting data according to this query (ASC/DESC)
 I need to dynamically sorting (ASC/DESC) depending on a conditional statement. my database system is mysql. Please help, i have been stuck with this issue for a long period of times.

For Example  :

```
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `updateStock`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updateStock`(IN `ProductID` INT, IN `OrderQuantity` INT, IN `MethodType INT`, OUT `result_p` INT)
proc_label : BEGIN

declare TotalStock INT DEFAULT 0 ;

SET
  TotalStock =(
  SELECT
    SUM(a.QTY)
  FROM
    bf_inv_current_stock AS a
  WHERE
    a.MODEL_ID = ProductID
) ;

IF (TotalStock < OrderQuantity) THEN  
    LEAVE proc_label;      
END IF;

  begin
    declare InventoryID INT;
    declare QuantityInHand INT;
    declare v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    declare getinventoryid_cursor cursor for  select id,qty from bf_inv_current_stock WHERE model_id = ProductID ORDER BY id ASC/DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `order by` in `case`.

```
DECLARE getinventoryid_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    id, 
    qty 
FROM 
    bf_inv_current_stock 
WHERE model_id = ProductID 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN methodType = 1 THEN id END ASC,
    CASE WHEN methodType = 0 THEN id END DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00bd65/2)

Also there is an error in your procedure:

[image]

Comment: I put the code according to your suggestion but i am getting error. please help

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am still stuck @Hooman. I put the code but i am getting error. Should i provide entire procedure?

Comment: It is procedure parameter like -  IN `MethodType` INT

Comment: Then you need to use @methodType, if it is parameter! it's not really clear from your question where it does come from.

Comment: I update my question, provide full procedure, please help me. indicate ASC/DESC, It is working fine when i write statically ASC or DESC , but i need dynamically change asc to desc depending on methodeType parameter

Comment: What's the error? are you sure the problem is in order by?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' OUT `result_p` INT)
proc_label : BEGIN
    

  begin
    declare Invento' at line 1

Comment: please help me to sort out issue

Comment: That error has nothing to do with order by, I highlighted the problem in the answer.

Comment: okay i fixed and try to run once again, but still getting error, please help me to find out bugs

Comment: Please remove the minus mark for how i asked question.  Thanks a lot. Now it is working. I accept your answer.